# When designing an Android app, will the "default" theme be different on different devices?

Tags: android, interface-design, xml

I am currently designing the UI for my first Android app. Android (obviously) lets you design any and every element in your app using XML.

On any elements where you leave the "default" (holo) theme on, will that element appear different on different devices. Certain widgets (such as the spinner) match my theme perfectly but I was curious as to whether they will appear different on different versions of Android.

I am designing for Android 4.4.2.

Answer (score 1):

Specifying no theme will not always result in the device default theme, so if you want to display the default theme then you will have to specifically mention it.

You can declare a theme in your values/styles.xml and then in your values-v11/styles.xml override it with the Holo-version (This way, you'll have Holo themes on API 11+ devices and regular themes on the others) :

values/styles.xml:

```
<style name="DialogTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"></style>
```

values-v11/styles.xml:

```
<style name="DialogTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog.NoActionBar"></style>
```

And if you are specifically targeting `Android 4.4.2` then the appearance will be same on all devices that have `Android 4.4.2`